# SQL Server and compatibility mode - performance

Tags: sql-server

We need to move an enterprise ERP during the upgrade (from 2005 to 2008). I have done some reading regarding the merits of running compatibility mode and I know there are some differences in the SQL estimator running native vs. compatibility mode, but I was wondering if any of you have encountered any performance improvements running a SQL database in compatibility mode on a newer server, i.e. are there any papers or actual experience that suggest that I am going to get better performance running SQL2008 vs. SQL2014 with Compat mode on the database.  Do I actually benefit from the new server.  We are licensed either way and the ERP is only "guaranteed" on 2008.

I hope to get some feedback for anyone who has run into this problem before. (Compatibility has been around for a long time, so I am sure someone has). Considering that our databases are ~400GB, clustered and SAN'd makes a really real-world test somewhat difficult to really do. Even more-so that the SAN will "prioritise" things - just make the test even more difficult. We all know that SQL 2014 performs better than 2012, but with the poorest of data, it may be the case - hence the general request.

Comment: I have saved your comment before deleting my answer in case you no longer have access to it after deletion. (I don't know the Stack Overflow visibility rules for low-rep users.)

Comment: @Kermit Microsoft Dynamics does not run on MySQL and we have MSSQL resources at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have never run into any issues with compatibility mode for any version of SQL Server. I also haven't really noticed any performance benefits or drawbacks doing so, but I admit that I haven't done any real timing tests. Usually when I've had to do that, I've upgraded the hardware on the box, so a true comparison is difficult.

Having said that, are you sure that's the way you want to go?

Why not just run a test environment with the database migrated to 2008 and no compatibility? If everything works for you in the test environment, then upgrade directly.

Most SQL Server upgrades are pretty painless, unless you're trying to skip a version or two, which you aren't. Even in failover clusters they aren't that hard as long as you follow the step-by-step procedure from Microsoft.

Comment: I am trying to think "future" and limit the number of SQL versions running. Sometimes there client tools can be a bit spotty between versions, like activity monitor on server 2005 does not work with 2008R2 and above client tools.

Comment: I am trying to think "future" and limit the number of SQL versions running. Sometimes there client tools can be a bit spotty between versions, like activity monitor on server 2005 does not work with 2008R2 and above client tools.

Comment: Yes, that might be true, but that's more of a question of what versions of the client tools that you want to run, not the server. If you take the upgrade path I suggested to get you to 2008 with no compatibility, that will work with your 2008R2 client tools.

Comment: I would run SQL2015, if it was out :)